# How to modify numeric-comp style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

How can I modify the numeric-comp style in biblatex to achieve the following kind of bibliography:

> D. Goss, A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at
>   the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function, *Proc. Am. Math.
>   Soc.*, **81**, no. 4 (1981), 513-517.

Right now due to some internet problem I am unable to install additional packages, so I am limited to using the standard packages. I took a look at the other answers on this website but either they require me to install some additional package or they are not suitable for me.

Currently, what I get is:

> David Goss. "A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at
>   the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function". In: *Proc. Am. Math.
>   Soc.* 81.4 (1981), pp 513-517.

Thanks

Comment: What are the differences with the default?

Comment: Without anything to test: `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}` and `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. It took me too long to see all the minor differences. Please ask only one thing at the time, this is no custom-bib service.

[image: shahabBiblatexNumericMod]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{number}{}{%
  \printtext{no\adddot\addspace}%
  }%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to produce what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mynum-compbib.bib}
@article{ruoff,
author = "David Goss",
title = "A simple approach to the analytic continuation and values at the negative integers for the Riemann zeta function",
journal= "Proc. Am. Math. Soc.",
volume = "81",
number = "4",
pages = "513--517",
year = 1981,
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mynum-compbib.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addspace}%
}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}

\renewcommand\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
page = {},
pages = {},
}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\addcomma\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\isdot
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{number}{}{%
\printtext{no\adddot\addnbthinspace}%
}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article]

\end{document}
```

[image]