# Customization of the numeric-comp style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-phys

As explained in [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248740/how-to-modify-numeric-comp-style-in-biblatex), I want to highlight certain references when they are cited in the main text, e.g., [A2] instead of [2]. As I learned from Alan Munn's answer to my previous question, I have to modify the `cite:print` macros that are used by the `phys` style. The following minimal example shows that I do not always get the desired highlighting:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend = biber,style = phys]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{art1,
      author = {A. Nobody},title={Title A},
}
@article{art2,
      author = {B. Nobody},title={Title B},
}
@article{art3,
      author = {C. Nobody},title={Title C}
}
@article{art4,
      author = {D. Nobody},title={Title D}
}
@article{art5,
      author = {E. Nobody},title={Title E}
}
@article{art6,
      author = {F. Nobody},title={Title F}
}
@article{art7,
      author = {G. Nobody},title={Title G}
      }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\addtocategory{catA}{art2}
\addtocategory{catA}{art4}
\addtocategory{catA}{art6}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \ifcategory{catA}{A}{}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    
\makeatletter 
\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
      {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
      {}%
    \ifcategory{catA}{A}{}%
    \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:subentry:comp}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \printtext[entrysetcount]{\cbx@lastentrysetcount}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
      {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
      {}%
      \ifcategory{catA}{A}{}%
    \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \cite{art1},\cite{art2},\cite{art3},\cite{art4},\cite{art5},\cite{art6},\cite{art7}.
    This works fine: \cite{art1,art2,art3,art4}, \cite{art1,art2,art3}, \cite{art2,art3,art4}  \\
    
    What I get: \cite{art1,art2,art3,art4,art7}  \cite{art1,art2,art3,art6} \\
    What I want to get [1-A4, 7], [1-3, A6].
    
    \printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

As one can see, whenever there is an additional number after one of the compressed citations, e.g., [1-4, 7], the last number somehow causes the second last number to be printed in the same style: I get a 4 instead of A4, or an A3 instead of a 3 in the second example:

[image]

At first, I thought that I forgot to redefine some `comp` macros, but after looking at the `numeric-comp.cbx` file, I think I should be able to get want I want with the macros that appear in the above example.

Why does the number after a compressed citation inherit its style to the second number of the compressed citation?

(Despite the similar caption, my problem is not related to [How to modify numeric-comp style in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248740/how-to-modify-numeric-comp-style-in-biblatex) .)

Comment: Did you find a solution since then? I am struggling with the same issue.